# nodeJS fails to assign variable

Tags: node.js, debugging, variable-assignment

I'm facing this weird issue with a nodeJS 8.10 snippet.

consider the following object:

```
installments: {
    baseAmount: 294,
    expired: 304,
    settle: 2697
}
```

Now I have the following snippet

```
let amount
const amountChoice = choice.text //comes as string
...
switch (amountChoice) {
  case '1':
    amount = installments.baseAmount
    console.log(installments.baseAmount)
    console.log(amount)
    console.log(typeof installments.baseAmount)
    console.log(typeof amount)
    break
....
```

Now for the weird part, the console.log lines prints as follow

```
294 // installments.amount
undefined // amount
undefined // typeof installments.amount
undefined // typeof amount
```

I tried to parseInt and toString the installments.amount but both throws exceptions of NaN or cannot toString of undefined.

This is driving me nuts! did I just found a bug or something?

Comment: You have certified if the amountChoice var is passing with '1' ?

Comment: yep, otherwise the console.log wont be triggered?

Comment: Probably amount does not exist in your switch scope. You tried with var amount ?

Comment: well I declared it for the first time there... undefinded at the begining as excepted.

There is something weird, if I remove the word "base" to "baseAmount" it works! :S
thing is I cannot change that, as it comes from an external API